# Toggle with hover/click with list items

Tags: jquery, list, select, hover, toggle

I'm trying to accomplish something that has a few different elements, each of which I can get to work individually, but when I try to combine them, I get nothing.

The goals: 
1) upon hover of list item text, toggle/fade description div.
2) upon click of list item text, "pin" description div
3) upon click of same list item, "unpin" description div
4) upon click of different list item, "unpin" whatever is already pinned so that it fades out, and "pin" the new item so that it sticks.

I have a list set up like this:

```
 <ul>  
  <li><a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>  
  <div class="description">some text to be revealed</div>  
  </li>  
  <li><a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>  
  <div class="description">some text to be revealed</div>    
  </li>
 </ul>
```

And here is the jquery I have so far:

```
$(function() {  
//creates toggle fade effect
jQuery.fn.fadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {   
  return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);   
};   
$(".thumblist li").hover(function() {  
  if(!$(this).data('pinned'))  
    $(this).children(".description").fadeToggle();  
});  
$(".thumblist li").click(function() {  
  $('.liselected').removeClass('liselected');  
  $(this).children('.description').addClass('liselected');  
  $(this).data('pinned', !$(this).data('pinned'));  
});  
});
```

I have everything working but the last item. I've tried removing the .liselected class from all list items and then adding it to the current onclick, but it is failing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

One way I've found to achieve this is with the folllowing:

```
$('li').hover(
    function(){
        var fadeDiv = $(this).find('.description');
        if ($(fadeDiv).hasClass('pinned')){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(fadeDiv).fadeIn(500);
        }
    },
    function(){
        var fadeDiv = $(this).find('.description');
        if ($(fadeDiv).hasClass('pinned')){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(fadeDiv).fadeOut(500);
        }
    }).click(
    function(){
        $('.pinned').removeClass('pinned');
        $(this).find('.description').addClass('pinned');
    });
```

Coupled with the CSS:

```
.description {
    display:none;
}
.description.pinned,
.pinned.description {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s8XG9/1/).

---

**Edited** with an update to the [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s8XG9/8/):

```
$('li').hover(
    function(){
        var fadeDiv = $(this).find('.description');
        if ($(fadeDiv).hasClass('pinned')){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(fadeDiv).fadeIn(500);
        }
    },
    function(){
        var fadeDiv = $(this).find('.description');
        if ($(fadeDiv).hasClass('pinned')){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(fadeDiv).fadeOut(500);
        }
    }).click(
    function(){
        $(this)
            .closest('ul')
            .find('.pinned')
            .removeClass('pinned')
            .trigger('mouseleave');
        $(this)
            .find('.description')
            .addClass('pinned');
    });
```

This does give the '#4 behaviour,' the problem I was having, before, was that I based a function on the `mouseleave` (the second function of the `hover()` method), and then forgot to trigger that when removing the class-name in the click handler. Sigh...

References:

- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).
- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).
- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: I'm not getting the #4 behavior I'm looking for with your example. I just checked your Fiddle and it does what my original example already does: http://jsfiddle.net/rfyxD/61/

Comment: @f8xmulder, sorry about that; I had a slip of the, uh, mind when I put the first version together. I think I've rectified it with the updated demo. If you could take a look, and see if it does what you need?

Comment: Yep, your update worked. Thanks for doing the legwork. Did you see the solution I posted below? I ended up "fiddling" with it until I got it working, and even managed to add in an unmentioned feature. I'm curious which solution offers the best return in terms of size...

Answer (score 1):

I've finally gotten this jQuery to work as specified above:

```
$('.thumblist li').hover(function() {
  var fadeDiv = $(this).find('.description');

  if ($(fadeDiv).hasClass('pinned')){
      return false;
  } else {
    $(fadeDiv).fadeIn(500);
  }
}, function(){
  var fadeDiv = $(this).find('.description');
  if ($(fadeDiv).hasClass('pinned')){
    return false;
  } else {
    $(fadeDiv).fadeOut(500);
  }  
});

$('.thumblist li').click(function() {
  var fadeDiv = $(this).find('.description');
  $('.pinned').removeClass('pinned');
  $(fadeDiv).addClass('pinned');
  $('.thumblist li').children('.description').not('.pinned').delay(100).fadeOut(400);
}).hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings().find('.description').removeClass('pinned');
  $(this).siblings().find('.description').fadeOut(400); 
});
```

There's probably an easier/more elegant way to do this, but I'm not much of a jQuery guru.
Here's the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/rfyxD/119/

I added another feature to this, which will keep a clicked item persistent until you hover over a different li.